# Passing command line arguments to nightwatch.runner

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a test setup that accepts dynamic values for predefined options (e.g: --foo="bar", --foo="car", etc) which works perfectly when run from the command line.

This works:

`./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/nightwatch ./tests/test.js --env "production" --foo="bar"`

However, I want to call the test from inside a node app, but can't quite seem to get the extra parameters passed into my test. My test initializes correctly, but then fails because I can't get any of the extra params.

```
try {
    const nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

    const argv = {
        config: 'nightwatch.json',
        test: 'test.js',
        env: 'default',
        foo: 'bar',
    };

    const done = function() {
        console.log('nightwatch complete');
    }; // your callback function

    const settings = {};

    nightwatch.runner(argv, done, settings);

} catch (error) {
    console.log('Exception:' + error.message);
}
```

There seems to be absolutely no documentation for nightwatch.runner or nightwatch.cli so any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(argv)` before `Nightwatch.runner(argv)` in `node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js`, and run a few commands.  The debug output suggests some fields are missing from `argv`.

Comment: Thanks mate, it didn't quite work, but lead me down the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a lot of poking around to see what gets set where, but finally I tried playing with the settings object and realized that I could override the globals param like so:

```
var settings = {
    globals: {
        foo: 'one',
        bar: 'two'
    }
};
```

This probably isn't the intended functionality of the settings object here, but it worked for me.

```
try {
    const nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

    const argv = {
        config: 'nightwatch.json',
        test: 'test.js',
        env: 'default',
        foo: 'bar',
    };

    const done = function() {
        console.log('nightwatch complete');
    }; // your callback function

    var settings = {
        globals: {
            foo: 'one',
            bar: 'two'
        }
    };

    nightwatch.runner(argv, done, settings);

} catch (error) {
    console.log('Exception:' + error.message);
}
```

If anyone who comes across this is interested, I posted a very simple version on [github](https://github.com/alexdelgado/nightwatch-runner).